# Google Wallet JWT "exp" parameter

Tags: android-pay, jwt

I am integrating google wallet on my website, and didn't find the answer to this anywhere. Can the "exp" parameter of the JWT token be more than an hour? I see on every guide or library:

'exp' => time() + 3600,

But, could it be something else? like 2 hours:

'exp' => time() + 7200,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [spec](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#expDef)

> The exp (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing. The processing of the exp claim requires that the current date/time MUST be before the expiration date/time listed in the exp claim. Implementers MAY provide for some small leeway, usually **no more than a few minutes, to account for clock skew**. Its value MUST be a number containing a NumericDate value. Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.)

I personally haven't tested the "max" that Google will allow. However, it *could* matter to *you* more - re: how long is that *specific* transaction supposed to be "good". (When) should it expire/be invalidated? Should I be worried of replays?

Hth...